# global variables are returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, alert, var

I've written a simple page that has an alert of whatever's written in the text box.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            var sourceTest = "songs/" + document.getElementById("inputSong").value + ".mp3";

            function jukeBox()
            {
                alert(sourceTest);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text"; id="inputSong" style="display: inline; float: left";></input>
        <button 
            id="butter";
            type="button"; 
            onclick="jukeBox()"; 
            style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; float: left"> 
                Play 
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the alert is returning as undefined, unless I do this;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function jukeBox()
            {
                var sourceTest = "songs/" + document.getElementById("inputSong").value + ".mp3";
                alert(sourceTest);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text"; id="inputSong" style="display: inline; float: left";></input>
        <button 
            id="butter";
            type="button"; 
            onclick="jukeBox()"; 
            style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; float: left"> 
                Play 
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get this to work using a global variable, instead of a local one.

-Edit-

I moved the entire script to the body, and that appears to have fixed the problem.

Comment: If you don't want to fetch the value of the input field dynamically, then moving the script to body will work... else it won't

Comment: You are eating your sandwich before you make it. You are trying to reference an element before it is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first example `var sourceTest = "songs/" + document.getElementById("inputSong").value + ".mp3";` is evaluated only once when the page is loaded, since the script is in header it is executed before the dom element is created so `document.getElementById("inputSong")` will return null causing an error(in your browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`) so the value of the variable becomes undefined.

Since you want to fetch the value of the input field, you can really uses global variable in this case.

---

If you still want to use a global variable, you can either store the static parts of the string in a global variable and use it for string concatenation in the click handler or use a regex and replace a template part in the click handler

```js
var prefix = "songs/",
  suffix = ".mp3";

function jukeBox() {
  var sourceTest = prefix + document.getElementById("inputSong").value + suffix;
  alert(sourceTest);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" ; id="inputSong" style="display: inline; float: left" ;/>
<button id="butter" ; type="button" ; onclick="jukeBox()" ; style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; float: left">
  Play
</button>
```

Or

```js
var sourceTest = "songs/{inputSong}.mp3";

function jukeBox() {
  var value = sourceTest.replace(/\{inputSong\}/, document.getElementById("inputSong").value)
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" ; id="inputSong" style="display: inline; float: left" ;></input>
<button id="butter" ; type="button" ; onclick="jukeBox()" ; style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; float: left">
  Play
</button>
```

Comment: @Cain I don't think that will fix the issue as you won't get the updated values from the input field... The variable `sourceTest` will always have the initial value of the `input` field

Comment: The issue i was trying to resolve was a way to get the alert to sound without putting the variable in the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a script it's working

```js
function jukeBox(){
    var input = "songs/" +document.getElementById("inputSong").value+ ".mp3";
    alert(input);
}
```